# Proving a set is a linear subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $E$ is a vector space over $K$ and $F$ is a subset of $E$.
For $F$ to be a linear subspace then $\forall u,v \in F$ and $\forall \alpha,\beta\in K$, $\alpha u + \beta v \in F$

My professor has been using $\beta=1$, how is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\beta=0$, then $\alpha u + \beta v = \alpha u \in F$ which should be true if $F$ is a subspace of the vector space $E$

So, you can suppose that $\beta \neq 0$, now divide things by $\beta$ which is non-zero. Since the statement must be true for all $\alpha$, you can assume that $\alpha/\beta$ is another $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: @Luyw You're welcome.